# In Struts2,How could i redirect control to a java file from a jsp page ,without the use of a form submision?

Tags: struts2

In Struts2,How could i redirect control to a java code from a jsp page ,without the use of a form submision?

Comment: A `GET` request? What are you asking?

Comment: I want a jsp page to open,then have to view data from an arraylist.but how could i initialize the values in arraylist at the time,i enter the page????

Comment: In an action; in an S2 app you should never hit a JSP page directly.

Comment: @user1182156: i am curious why you don't want to use tags and proper request cycle?

Answer (score 0):

[Call action inside jsp](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/action.html)

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you would like to use Java code in the execution flow of jsp. You can write the code in the class file and later on use the scriptlets to access it.

Please refer the link below:

[Scriptlets](http://www.jsptut.com/Scriptlets.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect within **scriptlets**

```
<% response.sendRedirect("myclass"); %>
```

or

where myclass is class name I used in struts.xml

if you want to use any conditions before this statement then you can make it as a conditional redirect, like

```
<%
    if(condition){
     response.sendRedirect("search1"); %>
    }
    else{

        response.sendRedirect("search2");
    }
%>
```

otherwise if you want to use **javascript** you can use

```
window.location='mypage.jsp';
```

or

```
window.location='myclass';
```